# Catch all exceptions in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering if anybody would have an idea to catch all exceptions in a running thread. My program is started as follow, by a service

```
def main():
    global RUNNING

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stopHandler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stopHandler)

    projectAlice = ProjectAlice()
    try:
        while RUNNING:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        projectAlice.onStop()
        _logger.info('Project Alice stopped, see you soon!')
```

So a CTRL-C or a signal can stop it. ProjectAlice runs forever and answers to mqtt topics that are sent by Snips. It uses paho-mqtt with loop_forever. As it's pretty large, errors can occur, even though they shouldn't. I cover as many as I can, but today, as an exemple, google-translate started to throw out errors, because it can't use the service anymore (free...). Unhandled errors.... So the thread crashes and ProjectAlice is left as is. I would like to, as it's possible per exemple in Java, to super catch all exceptions and work further from there

Comment: You are doing it upside down, this will only catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, so far I know... But even trying to add other exceptions here or a simple catch doesn't catch all the exceptions, in fact it doesn't catch anything. I somehow would need to subscribe to exceptions

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt does not inherit from Exception, if you want to catch all exceptions including SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt, you should use BaseException.

Comment: And by the way, it's normal that your try/except block does catch exceptions, because... well, there is nothing that would raise an exception ! you're simply evaluating a global variable and calling time.sleep

Comment: Thank you, but I think you don't understand. I showed how it's started. I know the loop with the try-catch isn't what's needed.... I asked for a class to catch exceptions occurring during runtime. The try catch you see here is only to stop the execution when manually started

Comment: The question is pretty easy: "I would like to, as it's possible per exemple in Java, to super catch all exceptions and work further from there"

Comment: Oh, ok, I misunderstood when I saw your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution to override the python exception hook, thus enabling you to handle uncaught exceptions:

```
import sys

def my_custom_exception_hook(exctype, value, tb):
    print('Yo, do stuff here, handle specific exceptions and raise others or whatever')
```

and before your actual code starts do:

```
sys.excepthook = my_custom_exception_hook
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `except Exception:` will catch all exceptions except KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit *within the same thread*.

You'll have to have the `try: except ...:` block within the code that is run in the thread to catch exceptions occurring in the thread.

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried, but I have many threads, thus the question, a class to catch all exceptions, bit like a subscriber

Comment: Ah, you didn't really say you have many threads (whose code, I assume, might not be in your control).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. And yes, they are not all on my control :)